# Slick.js variableWidth + infinite does not work in both directions

Tags: javascript, jquery, carousel, slick.js

For some reason, when you use VariableWidth + infinite, it is not infinite when you are using the prev button, .. only going forward with next.  Does anyone have any experience with this issue or have an hacks they might have employed to get past this.

ive attached a fiddle

[http://jsfiddle.net/vqx2qc7a/](http://jsfiddle.net/u68o5tmw/)

```
$('.variable-width').slick({
  dots: true,
  infinite: true,
  speed: 300,
  slidesToScroll: 2,
  variableWidth: true
});
```

Answer (score -1):

add

```
 centerMode: true,
```

I don't see other way.
or use flickity http://flickity.metafizzy.co/